# Natural Languages supported by Einstein Bots

Tags: einstein

In which natural languages can I develop Einstein Bots. Google's DialogFlow, for example, has 16 languages.

Comment: this says English only - https://metamind.readme.io/v2/docs

Answer (score 0):

You don't do anything with Einstein Bot's natural language. It is not open. What Einstein Bot does allow is configure the Q&A so that you can take care of client's myriad needs.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that Einstein Bots has evolved since the answer given earlier and now supports 8 different langauges with more on the way as of this writing.